# Repeater destroy repeated items

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flex4, adobe

I am stuck in improving the performance of repeater. I have repeater(recycleChildren = "true") with a custom repeating component in a pop up window.

The problem is when I close the popup window it does not destroys the instances of repeater item. When I repeater the popup window profiler show the instances count as: reptur.dataProvider.lenght + the instances that were there at the time of closing the popup window.

So the memory shoots up & not release as I close & open the window.

Please help me out in releasing the repeater instances on cosing the window.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know it doesn't answer your question but I see you use Flex 4. If I were you, I would use a DataGroup instead of a Repeater

Answer (score 0):

try [`System.gc()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#gc%28%29)

 or set them to `null` manually

Comment: @ gauravflex - what about re-creating their parent object?